# using HQL in one to many relations when hibernate generate own table and we've not that table/entity in our Entity Models

Tags: hibernate, hql, self-join

when i try model a oneToMany self relation on `RuleEntity`, hibernate generate `rule_rule`table in db to handling this matter , now the question is : because i haven't this entity(rule_rule) in my domain so i can't do HQL to find `relatedRules` that related to some rule :)
how can i do this?

**RuleEntity**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<RuleEntity> relatedRules;
```

the point is --> for some business reasons i cant't use Native Sql in this situation

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Dudes, i find it :)

`select r.ruleName from RuleEntity r JOIN r.relatedRules rr where rr.ruleName = 'myRule'`

this query find RuleEntities which have relatedRule with name "myRule"